# Has the polynomial $z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 2z + 3$ any real zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I want to determine in which quadrants the zeros of the polynomial $z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 2z + 3$ are. The argument principle comes to my mind, but to be able to apply that theorem, I must make sure that the polynomial doesn't have any zeros on the negative real axis. (Obviously it doesn't have any zeros on the positive real axis.) Is there an easy way of excluding the possibility of negative real zeros? The only way I can think of is cumbersome at best and flawed at worst.

Comment: Write it as sum of squares by splitting the $4z^2$ term

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Many users in this forum won't even read your questions if they're not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Conrad. What do you mean by "splitting"? Is it possible to get rid of the problematic terms z^3 and 2z somehow?

Comment: Prove it has no real zero at all (e.g. substract $(z^2+z/2)^2$ and look at the remaining quadratic polynomial). This was [easy to predict](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+z%5E4+%2B+z%5E3+%2B+4z%5E2+%2B+2z+%2B+3). However, I wonder how you will then use the argument principle.

Comment: Thanks, Anne. I will apply the argument principle to a big, left semi circle and finally use the complex conjugate root theorem to distribute the zeroes evenly between the second and third quadrants.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, Gonçalo. A problem with Conrad's method seems to be that we can't use in some other cases. For example, what happens if the z^2 term has coefficient 1 instead of 4? Then it's not possible to rewrite the polynomial as a sum of squares, I think, but it still lacks real zeros according to computer plots.

Comment: Well, your post is not about other polynomials. Your post is about this polynomial.

Comment: Yes, Lee, but that doesn't stop me from wondering if the proposed method is applicable in other cases as well.

Comment: Great, Gonçalo! I'm impressed that you were able to write also that polynomial as a sum of squares. How did you find a way to do it? What's the procedure? It seems like you had to split both the z^4 term and the 4z^2 term, not just the latter as in the previous case. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Method-1:

You could use the second derivative test to prove that the function has a local minima at the point $(-0.276,2.737)$.

Since the local minima is greater than zero, this leads one to assume that the function does not cross the x-axis (in which case, its local minima would have ben less than or equal zero), hence, the function has no real roots.

Details:
$$f(z)=z^4 + z^3 + 4z^2 + 2z + 3$$
$$f'(z)=4z^3+3z^2+8z+2$$
$$f''(z)=12z^2+6z+8$$

When $f'(z)=0$, leads to single real root at $z=-0.276$. This root may be found in any way including the [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s%20formula:%7E:text=a%20cube%20root.-,Cardano%27s%20formula,-%5Bedit%5D), or by other means.
Now $f''(-0.276)=7.258112>0$, hence there is a local minima for $f(z)$ at $z=-0.276$.

Method-2:

You could use the Quartic [Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) approach. When you do the calculations, you get the value of the Discriminant=$229$, which is positive. This indicates that $f(z)$ has either all roots as real numbers or all roots are complex number. Since the rational roots test for $f(z)$ fails, the roots of $f(z)$ are all complex numbers.

Finally, you can check [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve%20Power%5Bz%2C4%5D%20%2B%20Power%5Bz%2C3%5D%20%2B%204Power%5Bz%2C2%5D%20%2B%202z%20%2B%203%3D0) to obtain the exact 4 complex root values.

I hope this makes sense.